# Setting Primary key in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

This is my code to load EditScreen for User Model.

```
@login_required ()            
def getUser (request, userId):

    if request.method  == "GET":
        my_record = User.objects.get(user_id=userId)
        form = UserUpdateForm (instance=my_record)

        print "Registration page loading..."

        return render(request, "EN/updateuser.html", {'form': form } )
```

But 'user_id' (PrimaryKey) is not going as part of 'form' when I get request for update User I'm not able to get the object instance to update it. How to set it along with the form so that I should be able to read it. I thought of setting it through Hidden Value but I felt that is not a safe way.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to send it as part of the form? You have it in the URL already (and therefore as the `userId` argument to the view), there's no need to get it from anywhere else.

Comment: YES; but when I update how can retrieve the 'user_id' as I'll be in 'updateuser.html'

Comment: I don't know what you mean about being "in" a template. The Django pattern is to post back to the same view which rendered the form in the first place, so it will still have the same URL parameters.